# add object from type SCNNode on ARSCNViwe

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, scnnode

i add SCNNode and append this object a gif
and I want to keep this object fixed at the bottom of the page .I want to keep this object fixed at the bottom of the page.

And its width should be in accordance with the width of the phone

```
  guard let pointOfView = self.pointOfView else { return }
        let gifImage = UIImage.gifImageWithName(fileUrl)

        let height = (gifImage?.size.height)! * gifImage!.scale
        let width = (gifImage?.size.width)! * gifImage!.scale
        let ratio = width/height
        let newHeight = ratio*height
        let newWidth = self.frame.width

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let gifNode = SCNNode()            
            let gifPlane = SCNPlane(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
            gifNode.geometry = gifPlane

            gifNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, -1)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let gifImageView = UIImageView(image: gifImage).layer
                self.updatePosition(node: gifNode)

                gifPlane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = gifImageView

                let orientation = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -1) // i have no idea about this 

                gifNode.position = orientation

                pointOfView.addChildNode(gifNode)                
            }
        }
```

but that's doesn't work well

[image: example 1]
[image: example 2]can you help me ?